# Building Workspace has encountered an issue, eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently updated the android SDK and also tools.

On creating a New Android Project I am getting this error.

[image: Problem]

I checked all the solutions and also tried them but nothing seems to work. How do I fix it?

Comment: HAve you tried restarting your system and also restart the eclipse ?Sometimes, the updates suck the environment.

Comment: it may failed to load sdk or some error occur loading sdk. restart your eclipse and it will work.

Comment: I had tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved...just needed to update my JDK.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update the ADT version using Eclipse's "Install New Software" feature and using { https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ } as the repository URL.

- In Eclipse go to Help
- Install New Software ---> Add
- inside Add Repository write the Name: ADT (or whatever you want)
      and Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- after loading you should get Developer Tools and NDK Plugins
- check both if you want to use the Native Developer Kit (NDK) in the future or 
      check Developer Tool only
- click Next
- Finish

Comment: Also did that but still the same problem

Comment: then You should download the new ADT bundle from the android website....It seems to be the best option....